# bootstrap jumbotron props overwrite mine

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put an image as a `background-image` in the whole section that contains a carousel and jumbotron , when I try the jumbotron makes the top of the section `#eceeef` and the bottom of the section has half of the image

This is the html

```
<!-- The main section  -->
  <div class="sectionColor">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotronModified">
      <div class="container">
        <img class="display-3" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/152aef_55aed5c543774335985696d9490acb58~mv2.png/v1/crop/x_12,y_0,w_672,h_209/fill/w_383,h_120,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/152aef_55aed5c543774335985696d9490acb58~mv2.png">
        <p class="lead">Since 1994</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="mainSection" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide col-md-6" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid imgMain" src="assets/tipsolahraga.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid imgMain" src="assets/board.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid imgMain" src="assets/longboard.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my SASS file

```
.sectionColor
    background-image: url(../assets/player.png)
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-size: cover
    padding-bottom: 4rem

#mainSection
    margin: auto
    padding-top: 3rem

.jumbotronModified
    text-align: center

.sectionLight
    background-color: #ffffff

.coachSection
    padding-top: 3rem
```

I found the problem , is that the jumbotron props class form bootstrap overwrite the background image to a background color by default `#eceeef`

I tried several ways to fix, but I have to change bootstrap either modify the class from bootstrap (and that is extremely inefficient the long term) or remove the whole class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about change the jumbutron's background color to transparent?

```
.jumbotronModified
    text-align: center
    background: transparent;
```